# "GNUTLS ERROR: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received." when mointing with ifuse

Tags: ipod

I use a macbook pro 3.1 with Ubuntu 10.04 as single boot; I have also added the `ppa:pmcenery/ppa`  to have the last updated library to use ipod and co., and upgraded the whole system.

I have some trouble trying to mount my iPod Touch because Nautilus does
not auto-mount it. I tried to manually mount it using ifuse:

```
r@mbp:~$ sudo mkdir /media/ipod
r@mbp:~$ sudo ifuse /media/ipod/
```

When I tried to open the ipod icon on the desktop I have: Access was
denied!

So, to browse the ipod I have to use:

```
r@mbp:~$ gksudo nautilus
```

Doing this I can not oped ipod in Rhythmbox. I also tried to change the
permission of the mounting point:

```
r@mbp:~$ sudo chmod 777 /media/ipod
```

but nothing changes. I also tried to use ifuse without sudo but I have
this error:

```
r@mbp:~$ ifuse /media/ipod
GNUTLS ERROR: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

Do you have any further suggestion??

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I know this may seem counter-intuitive, but please remove your solution from the question, and create it as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will let others who may have the same issue quickly find the solution.